# dc.js row chart with single negative row not showing

Tags: dc.js

I'm building a dashboard with the excellent `dc.js` library, and using a lot of row charts to depict performance across multiple layers of a network. The top layers only consist of one element, and for conformity reasons I want to depict these top layers with a row chart (with a single row) as well. However, performance values can be negative so in this case I want to show a single row in a row chart with a negative value.

This results in an empty chart. Here is a basic example of a similar situation:

```
var chart2 = dc.rowChart("#test2");

data2 = [{
  Expt: "1",
  Run: "2",
  Speed: -850
}];

var ndx2 = crossfilter(data2)
var runDimension2 = ndx2.dimension(function(d) { return +d.Run; })
var speedSumGroup2 = runDimension2.group().reduceSum(function(d) { 
    return d.Speed * d.Run / 1000; });

chart2
  .width(768)
  .height(100)
  .elasticX(true)
  .dimension(runDimension2)
  .group(speedSumGroup2)
  .render();
```

I created a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/BjRnJ/drvowj77/). I tried using the stable `dc.js 1.7.5` as well as 2.0.0 beta 26, the result was the same. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's a bug! Specifically [#879](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/879). I'm working on merging the comprehensive fix by Sebastian Gröhn for beta 32.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Gordon, I will wait for future releases. And thanks for the great work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug with charts with all-negative values - or to be precise, the chart was never designed to work with all-negative values, but Sebastian Gröhn submitted a patch.

It's fixed in 2.0 beta 32.